# Is being the second author always good?

Tags: authorship

I work in an institute where I am more concerned with Development of systems and solutions rather than actual research, but of course the head is a professor and writing papers is an important task when it comes to *productivity*. 
My ordeal is that I would rather be:

> on the programming, developing side of the research, where I like to give things a try than just writing ideas and concepts

I have however been a second author on a couple of papers; one a demo/poster paper and one for a conference (in the pipeline).

I have been stressing myself because I realize that writing papers isn't my thing but the work that I do is still enjoyable and fun and I would like to continue working as much as possible

Is being a second author most of the times accounts to something similar to publishing things as a first author?

Comment: Field? ........

Comment: Production Engineering / IT

Comment: What is your status? assistant professor or similar?

Comment: @Erwan Research Scientist. Not a professor or similar.

Comment: imho the only possible issue is in case this would slow down your career progression (assuming this matters to you, it doesn't even have to). I don't know if this is the case for research scientist

Answer (score 4):

This depends strongly on the field. In some, it is a big deal, in others not so much. But it is always a good thing to be an author, wherever you appear in the list.

If you are comfortable with it, don't worry too much. Your preferences may change, of course, in which case you may want to take more of a lead in the research and thus in the "perceived rank" of authorship.

Of course, your institution might put more emphasis on "first" authorship and it may affect your advancement. Don't neglect that.

In some fields we don't worry at all about that and just list names alphabetically, assuming that if they are listed, they contributed.

Comment: Is there an unofficial list which states which field has high stakes for authorship which fields dont?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of variables here. The author contributions section of the paper will matter a lot too. For example, I'm a biomedical statistician so I have a huge number of 2nd/3rd author papers where the author contributions statement says the 1st author designed the experiments and stuff, and I did all the stats.

If I'm applying to stats focused positions, that 2nd author 'did all the stats' contribution could mean more than a 1st author 'designed the experiment'. Make sure the author contributions statement accurately reflects what you did. This was commented on in my interview for my current position.